# Get Netflix DVD List Using Search Term

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to get a list of all DVDs listed in `dvd.netflix.com` that were released in a given year.

This is trivial if I want such a list for say, the year **1995**. For this, I merely log into my account in [dvd.netflix.com](https://dvd.netflix.com) and enter the string `1995` into the search box (FYI, execution of said search yields a result of 351 titles).

The problem arises when I want a similar list of titles released in 1997 or later. For example, when I enter `2010`, `2015`, or `2018` into said search box, I get 400 returns. I suspect that the website caps the search results at 400.

As a Linux user, how can I generate a list of ALL the titles released in, say, **2010**?